# why cannot I use "this" to use mystyle inside the class component?

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6

I have the code below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, view } from 'react-native';

class LoginForm extends Component {


  render() {
      return(
        <Text style={ styles.errorMessageStyle }>
          {this.props.auth.error}
        </Text>   
      );
  }
}

const styles = {
  errorMessageStyle: {
    fondSize: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
};
```

why when I use `this` at `style={ this.styles.errorMessageStyle }` it shows me error `Cannot read property 'errorMessageStyle' of undefind`.
but when I remove it works?

Comment: Because you don't understand what `this` means. `this` points to the current instance, but `styles` is declared as a const inside your module, and not bound to any instance

Comment: @Dummy  can you please add more details and post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your style object is not in your class and by using `this` you can access your class members.
If you want to do this you should define your style object in your class.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the current object, to be explicit LoginForm. Your `styles` variable is not part of `LoginForm`, thus cannot be called using `this`

```
class SomeObject extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    someVariable = "Hello, World"
  }

  someOtherMethod() {
    //...
  }


  render() {
     //...
  }
}

const someStyles = {

};
```

From the above example, you cannot use `this` to called `someStyles`, but for someVariable, it is within the scope of current object, therefore `this` can be used, the same goes for `someOtherMethod` method within the object

Comment: why my `styles` variable is not part of `LoginForm`

Comment: @farmcommand2 because it is being declared outside the class object. (Don't get Mixed up with class object with single jsx/js file

Comment: If you have multiple class within a file 'this' keyword would refer to the Class object that that piece of code is inside

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` refers to the current object. Your `style` declaration should go from:

```
const styles = {
```

to

```
this.styles = {
```

The last one must be inside your class.

Now you can use `this` inside `style`.

Answer (score 0):

`styles` is a `constant`. and `points` to the current instance.

if `styles` was a method of the `class` returning the style object then you could have used `this.styles()`, but in your case you defined it as a `constant`.

Hope this helps.